# Error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure with 1.15.0 with real device iphone 11 13.4 ios version

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium-ios

I am trying to automate iOS application using appium. I have done setting up in Xcode ( Performed clean, build and ran ) for the integration app to my real device and I observed the Integration app is installed into my real iphone 11 ( iOS version : 13.4) and then I checked for WebAgentRunner but it is not installed using xcode and later when I tried to connect to same real device using appium and trying to deploy my real app , I can install using appium but there are Error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure